Understanding of nominal p-values in sample size calculation
I need your help to understand the R-Output. In this example, two interim analyses were planned. The adjusted p-values are shown below. However, I am still not clear what the nominal p-values mean. Are these unadjusted values?


Please don't upload code, error messages, results or data as images for these reasons - and these.

These are the (unadjusted) P-values you'd have to observe to stop the study at that time, e.g. the first value is equal within rounding to pnorm(3.47, lower.tail=F).
